# Not able to communicate with Go gRPC service in Kubernetes

Tags: ssl, nginx, kubernetes, grpc, grpc-go

I am trying to run a gRPC service written in Golang inside Kubernetes. I am deploying the service (without any SSL). The Kubernetes also has `nginx` running with flag `--enable-ssl-passthrough`. I have a Go client which tries to call the gRPC service (without TLS) and I am getting the following error:

```
2020/03/20 18:12:54 rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = connection closed
exit status 1
```

When I do `kubectl exec` into the gRPC service pod and run the client code inside the pod (with address: `localhost:<port>`) then I am getting correct output. But I am not able to communicate with the gRPC service from outside.

Comment: Please share your yaml from pod and services. From where you are trying to communicate? Are you using pod ip, service ip, service name?

Comment: Try sending a simple TCP package with netcat to the server. That should at least help you determine wether traffic can be routed to the cluster Ingress Gateway.

Comment: Thanks for the help! The communication is working fine now. It needed to communicate over TLS (because nginx controller was expecting that).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `nginx controller` pod expected that the service it is redirecting to, works on TLS. Because I had not enabled secure gRPC inside server/client, the communication was not passing forward from the controller. I enabled TLS/SSL inside service and made secure communication from client and so it is working fine now!